# Parsing variable from one function to another

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller

I have a function that receives a UID from a web service and I need it to carry through that string to a function interrupt that posts a request back to the server with the matching UID after a button press.

How do I get the string from one function to the other?

```
const int buttonPin = D1;
const int ledPin = 13;

void fire(void);
volatile int state = LOW;

//#include <string.h>
char server[] = "xxxxxxxx.com";
TCPClient client;

// name the pins
int red = D3; //RED
int green = D4; //AMBER
int pinCommand;

void setup() {
//Register our Spark function here
Spark.function("led", ledControl);

for (int pin = D3; pin <= D4; ++pin) {
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
}
//set RED (D3) LED state to on
digitalWrite(D3, HIGH);
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
attachInterrupt(D1, fire, CHANGE);

Serial.begin(9600);
}

int ledControl(String command) {

//find out the pin number and convert the ascii to integer
int pinCommand = (command.charAt(0) - '0');
String UID = command.substring(2,8);
if ((pinCommand = 1)) {
    // GREEN (D5) LED TO ON, RED (D3) LED TO OFF
    digitalWrite(D4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(D3, LOW);
}

else {
    //GREEN (D5) LED TO OFF, RED (D3) LED TO On
    digitalWrite(D4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(D3, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Fail");
}
return 1;
}

void loop() {

}

void fire() {

if (digitalRead(D4) == HIGH) {
    state = !state;
    if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
            Serial.println("connected");
            client.println("POST /deployapp/"+UID+" HTTP/1.1");
            Serial.println(UID);
            client.print("Host: ");
            client.println(server);
            client.println("Accept: text/html, text/plain");
            client.println();
            client.flush();
        }

        else {    
            Serial.println("connection failed");
            client.stop();
        }
}

else {
    Serial.println("AUTHENTICATE FIRST");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is String and where is it defined ? Sorry , but I don't know if there is any string object predefined in C language .

Comment: This is the problem I'm having. I need to get the UID from ledControl and parse it back to void fire to send it to the client  but I can't find anything about carrying it across.

Comment: put the UID string in a char array that both the interrupt function and the main function can see.  I.E. use a static variable that outside any function.